# How to keep older components in install shield while update

Tags: updates, installshield

I have two components in install shield setup. Now I am going to remove those two components and new two components but I want to keep those older components when user update my product. 
Is there any way to keep older components while update ?

Comment: What is in those older components? This is an MSI installer? Are you using major upgrades?

Comment: In older have some files. Not an MSI installer. Don't know which type of update require for this.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you do not perform a Major Upgrade on the target system, the files associated with the deleted components will not be deleted from the system during an update.

Comment: Okay Thanks But what about if user upgrade the product ? if already installed

Comment: The files of deleted components will remain on the system during an upgrade, even if already installed.